# Change localhost to custom server ip address in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I 'ld like to use different server for my laravel project.For that i've changed my config/database.php code as,

```
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'http://192.168.1.15'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
```

And in .env file,

```
        APP_URL=http://192.168.1.15,
```

But it still access my localhost.How can I do this?

Comment: Restart server and try again

Comment: @AbuTaleb Now I 've the mysql server password in DB_PASSWORD in .env file  and it shows the error `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `users` where `id` = 96 limit 1)`

Comment: now try to set user name and password for http://192.168.1.15 at `.env` file

Comment: why are you using `http://192.168.1.15`? isn't it `192.168.1.15`? `DB_HOST` is not a HTTP protocal

Comment: `APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:2L1qSOZunurDk7NG5u6LLY4f47ci4wtmsNDGLMiKi8g=
APP_URL=192.168.1.15

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=movecab
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=mysql

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
`

Comment: @AbuTaleb here is my .env file I've changed it till shows the error

Comment: @JoshLin I've changed it

Comment: use shell ` mysql --host=192.168.1.15 --user=[user] --password=[password] mydb` to check if your user config in mysql is right